# To have names for figures in LaTeX

Tags: latex, figure

I need to have labels for figures. However, I am not sure where is the bug, since the following figure -command should be correct:

```
\begin{figure}\label{ERD figure}
        \includegraphics[width=13.0cm]{/Users/cs/pictures/user-cases.png}
\end{figure}
```

I removed already some commands from my main document. 
It solves the bug with the generation of table of contents.
However, I have not managed to find the reason for the fact that there is no label for any figures although I use them when converting to PDF.

**This is the main file.**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage, onecolumn]{article} 
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}                
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{url}   %urls formatting
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{backref,  
pdfpagemode=FullScreen,  
colorlinks=false,
pdfborder=0 0 0}


\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{program}{thp}{lop}

\floatname{program}{Program} %never use \newpage! Use \clearpage

\title{PC} 
\author{Masi}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\pagestyle{plain}

----------- picture here-----------------

\end{document}
```

**Do you know what is wrong in my .tex -document?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think latex supports png files.  Are you using a different latex-like processor?

\label's should go in \caption's

This is "the book" on the subject:
ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/epslatex.pdf

Answer (score 0):

pdflatex does support .png, but not vector graphics {.ps, .eps}. If you have all raster graphics{jpg, png, etc} just use pdflatex.

Comment: @dmckee: Do you mean that you can vector manipulation in PDF in the fileformats .ps and .eps?

Comment: NO, I mean that PDF support vector images. You *can* translate various postscript files into pdf for inclusion in pdflatex documents. see pdftops, pdf2ps, convert, etc...

Comment: sorry, i mean pdflatex does not natively support .ps or .eps. you can always convert file formats, but in my mind that is usually less than optimal.

Comment: There is no difference in quality between a vector (E)PS and a vector PDF. For bitmap data, they may use different compression but essentially EPS to PDF is or can be a lossless conversion.

Comment: Actually, pdftex does support including some EPS files provided they respect some strict conventions.

Comment: The output of metapost is an example. It's eps, but pdftex should be able to include the figures after a simple renaming (as .mps instead of .1 .2 .3 etc IIRC).
EPS is itself a "strict" version of postscript where some idioms must be respected so that the figure can be included in another file without funny results.

Comment: Back to the point, this answer is just wrong. Pdftex does support vector graphics, just not in the (general) PS or EPS format.